# How to compare clob columns of single table in oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle, clob

How to compare clob columns of single table  in oracle?

Comment: What have you tried to achieve your wanted results? What has your research concerning your problem shown? Can you provide code of your tries? [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [How much research effort is expected](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) might be helpful to improve your question.

Comment: What do you mean? How many columns? What properties do you want to compare? You're asking a bunch of strangers on the internet to spend **their time** helping you. The least you can do is invest some of your **your time** framing a proper question.

Answer (score 2):

This code should work:

```
select * 
    from table 
   where dbms_lob.compare(aClobColumn, bClobColumn) = 0
```

PS: I haven't tried running it as I am not having access to an Oracle instance at the moment.

Reference: https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ARPLS/d_lob.htm#ARPLS600